# How to find result with mongo-driver by objectid field

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I have 2 structs:

```
type Customer struct {
    MyID int    `bson:"myID"`
}
type Bag struct {
    Customer primitive.ObjectID `bson:"customer"`
}
```

But I dunno how to make filter to find document in Bag collection by Customer.MyID
I tried something like this:

```
filter := bson.D{{"customer", bson.D{{"myID", 123456789}}}}
cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)
```

Also tried this:

```
filter := bson.D{{"customer.myID", bson.D{{"$eq", 123456789}}}}
cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)
```

And I always get nothing in my cur variable. Please help me how to use it right.

Answer (score -1):

The collection name must not appear in the filter, the `collection` on which you call `Find()` already represents (or should) the `customer` collection, so just use:

```
collection := client.Database("yourdatabase").Collection("customer")

filter := bson.M{
    "myID": 123456789,
}
cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)
```

Or with `bson.D`:

```
filter := bson.D{{"myID", 123456789}}
```